# Can't control the opacity/fill of Circle Markers in IE11 (Google Maps Javascript API)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps built-in SymbolPath.Circle to render markers as Circles on the Map.

In both Chrome and Firefox this renders the circles quite nicely: [as seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kocFB.png)

However, in Internet Explorer 11, the interior of the circles gets filled in: [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnBxJ.png)

I have attempted to control the fill by setting opacity to 0, but to no avail. Curiously, when I try to inspect a marker DOM element in IE11, deleting it from the HTML tree does nothing. It seems that Google Maps somehow renders Circle Markers very differently in IE11 from Chrome/Firefox.

Does anybody have any ideas? This appears to be a bug with Google Maps, but any workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a code snippet of initializing a marker:

```
// Construct the marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: cities[city].center,
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 1,
        strokeWeight: cities[city].radius,
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8
    },    
    title: city,
    info: infoWindow,
});
```